# SASS Error The Dimension Has Attribute Loop

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssas, dimension

In trying to process a single SASS dimension from within Visual Studio 2012, I am encountering the error:

> the dimension has attribute loop

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured it out.  Turns out I had a circular reference in the dimension Attribute Relationships.  Attribute A was connected to Attribute B.  However, Attribute B already had a relationship defined in which it was connected to Attribute A.  If you go to the Attribute Relationships tab, it's very obvious what the issue is.